# How is react faster than Angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

From what I have read - React pushes all the DOM changes together. Can't angular do the same? After the digest cycle it knows which DOM node to change - why not publish it together?

Answer (score 0):

React 
utilize a virtual DOM
provide reactive and composable view components
maintain focus in the core library, with concerns such as routing and global state management handled by companion libraries

When rendering UI, manipulating the DOM is typically the most expensive operation and unfortunately, no library can make those raw operations faster. The best we can do is:

Minimize the number of necessary DOM mutations.  React use virtual DOM abstractions to accomplish this and both implementations work about equally well.

Add as little overhead (pure JavaScript computations) as possible on top of those DOM manipulations. This is an area where  React differ.
The JavaScript overhead is directly related to the mechanisms of computing the necessary DOM operations.

**Angular 1**

Angular 1 has strong opinions about how your applications should be structured.
Angular 1 uses two-way binding between scopes.

Directives are meant to encapsulate DOM manipulations only, while components are self-contained units that have their own view and data logic. In Angular, there’s a lot of confusion between the two.

Comment: So minimizing the DOM mutations is the key right? Angular can figure that out pretty easily after the digest cycle - it knows exactly what scope values have changed and that's what makes 2 way binding possible. Whatever scope values have changed those would be updated to Dom.